# How to add additionalProperties: false to every object in a json-schema Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework, jsonschema

Assume I have a complex json-schema

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "first_name": { "type": "string" },
    "last_name": { "type": "string" },
    "birthday": { "type": "string", "format": "date" },
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": { "type": "string" },
        "city": { "type": "string" },
        "state": { "type": "string" },
        "country": { "type" : "string" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to add `additionalProperties: false` to ALL object in the schema.
I'm using `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.7.4"` for handling JSON in my application. Is there an easy way to to so? Are there any other libraries I can use?

I managed to do it in the following way:

```
val strictJson = json.replaceAll("\"type\": \"object\",\n", "\"type\": \"object\",\n\"additionalProperties\": false,\n")
```

obviously it is not a good solution, I would like to do it with the Json library

Comment: The easiest way to do this is by hand. Are you asking if there's some automated way? You could write some code?

Comment: @Relequestual I’m asking for a starting point for doing it ‘by hand’ how do I traverse the Json and modifying it with Scala and play-json

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Could you maybe phrase that a different way?

Comment: How do I traverse play.api.libs.json.Json ? I want to find all json objects with property "type": "object" and add the property "additionalProperties": false @Relequestual

Comment: Oh right, you can't just edit the original JSON files?

Comment: just edited the question with my code snippet

Comment: That will only work where you have defined type as being an object. It will not work for all schemas, as `type` isn't required.

Comment: good point. so what do you suggest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222518/discussion-between-relequestual-and-adi-ohana).

Comment: You can do it with draft 2019-09 and the `unevaluatedProperties` and `$recursiveRef` keywords, but it's not possible in earlier drafts.

Comment: @Ether can you share a reference?